# Posting a value to the backend when Switch is toggled on. Where do I write my endpoint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small card that has a toggle switch and I want it to post `true` when toggled on and `false` when toggled off. I have already created the card and the functionality. Just not sure where to create the endpoint that sends data to the backend.

Here is where the switch works.

```
<div style={{ paddingLeft: "35px" }}>
  <div className="order-card">
    <div className="header-section">
      <h2 className="card-titles">Customer Notifications</h2>
    </div>
    <h4 style={{ padding: "12px 15px" }} className="order-title">
      Send customers reminders before auto-payment date
    </h4>
    <div style={{ width: "70%", textAlign: "left" }}>
      <Switch
        checked={this.state.isNotificationEnabled}
        onChange={e =>
          this.setState({
            isNotificationEnabled: e.target.checked
          })
        }
        color="primary"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When you toggle the switch on it changes state to true so `this.state.isNotificationEnabled = true`.

Now here is the question. Can I create the endpoint in `componentDidMount()`?

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.saveGmailInfo();
    console.log(
      "this.state.isNotificationEnabled",
      this.state.isNotificationEnabled
    );
    const code = this.props.history.location.query.code;
    if (code) {
      const ep = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/partners/zoom/auth`;
      const results = await axios.post(ep, { code });
      if (results.data.success) {
        this.setState({ zoom: true });
        this.props.history.push("/partners/customization");
        window.location.reload();
      } else {
        // toast.error(results.data.message)
        this.props.history.push("/partners/customization");
      }
    } else {
    }

    // get permissions for logo + dashboard
    await this.getLogoAndDashboardPermissions();
    await this.getThemePermissions();
    await this.getMailChimpPermissions();
    await this.getZoomPermissions();
  }
```

Right now when I toggle the Switch I don't see the console log below         `console.log("this.state.isNotificationEnabled",this.state.isNotificationEnabled)`
That means I am not hitting the function `componentDidMount`. How can I hit that function so I can create my endpoint in there?

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` only called once in the initial render.

you can call the function when then switch value changes.

```
<Switch
  checked={this.state.isNotificationEnabled}
  onChange={e => {
      this.setState({
        isNotificationEnabled: e.target.checked
      })
      // you can add code that sends the switch value to the backend 
    } 
  }
  color="primary"
/>
```